# javascript output doesn't show

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a simple program called guess a number. I'm having problem showing my output. So I don't know if i got the right formula.

```
<body>
<h3> Guess A Number</br> </h3><input type="integer" id="number" size="20"/>
<input type="button" id="guess" value="GUESS" onClick="guess()"/>

<script>
 function guess() {
 var num = document.getElementById("number").value; 
 var answer = Math.floor(Math.Random() * 100 + 1);

 if(num == answer)
     alert("Your guess is correct! The number is" + answer);

 else if(num != answer) 
     alert("Your guess is incorrect! The number is" + answer);

     }

</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Open up the Developer Console on your browser. It would have pointed you to the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a syntax error when generating a random number.

**It should be**

```
Math.random();
```

**But you have**

```
Math.Random();
```

Here is the complete code:

```
<body>
<h3> Guess A Number</br> </h3><input type="integer" id="number" size="20"/>
<input type="button" id="guess" value="GUESS" onClick="guess()"/>

<script>
 function guess() {
 var num = document.getElementById("number").value;
 var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

 if(num == answer)
     alert("Your guess is correct! The number is" + answer);

 else if(num != answer)
     alert("Your guess is incorrect! The number is" + answer);

     }

</script>
</body>
```

When developing Javascript, always have your browser's console turned on. It would have showed you this error. All browsers have consoles.

Comment: Lol thanks, didn't got that! I just started javascript just a few days ago. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but you need to test the function with a fixed number to see if it works, then use `Math.random();` (**lowercase `random()`**), in this case, I'm using `11` as the correct number..

```js
 function guess() {
 var num = document.getElementById("number").value; 
 //var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);
  var answer = 11;

 if(num == answer)
     alert("Your guess is correct! The number is" + answer);

 else if(num != answer) 
     alert("Your guess is incorrect! The number is" + answer);

     }
```

```html
<body>
<h3> Guess A Number</br> </h3><input type="integer" id="number" size="20"/>
<input type="button" id="guess" value="GUESS" onClick="guess()"/>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

// --- use Math.random instead of Math.Random ------

`

```js
<script>
 function guess() {
 
  var num = document.getElementById("number"); 
  //alert(num);
 var answer = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1);

 if(num == answer)
     alert("Your guess is correct! The number is" + answer);

 else if(num != answer) 
     alert("Your guess is incorrect! The number is" + answer); 

     }

</script>
```

```html
<body>
<h3> Guess A Number</br> </h3><input type="integer" id="number" size="20"/>
<input type="button" id="guess" value="GUESS" onClick="guess()"/>
</body>
```